# apt/apt-get update leads to error

Tags: apt, dpkg

**Edited:**

> Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
>
> Debian version: 11.5

[apt history](https://pastebin.com/x37TqcJ3) and [dpkg history](https://pastebin.com/18CrmFSY)

---

I tried to install multiple packages using `dpkg somefile.deb` but it hasn't completed as having dependency problems due to lack of the internet connection.

Now that I run 'apt update' or 'apt-get update', I get these errors:

```
apt-get: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
apt-get: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
apt-get: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
```

Comment: The usual problem is that you use a .deb not intended to be used for your specific distribution/version. You didn't specify what it is: is it Debian, Ubuntu, something else? Then which release of it? Once you know this you can ponder where you got the package from, and if it was intended for your distribution/version. Also if that's actually `apt-get` which complains, rather than the package to be installed, then you might have damaged your system and should give the history of what you installed and how. Part of the history can be found in /var/log/apt/ and /var/log/dpkg*

Comment: @A.B My server runs Debian 11.5 and yes, `apt-get` complains. I edited the original post and added the related logs you have mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is package `libstdc++6` which was upgraded to Debian testing/sid, preventing `apt-get`, which is a C++ application, to work anymore.

> ```
> 2022-10-18 10:37:01 upgrade libstdc++6:amd64 10.2.1-6 12.2.0-5
> 2022-10-18 10:37:01 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.31-13+deb11u4
> 2022-10-18 10:37:01 status half-configured libstdc++6:amd64 10.2.1-6
> 2022-10-18 10:37:01 status unpacked libstdc++6:amd64 10.2.1-6
> 2022-10-18 10:37:01 status half-installed libstdc++6:amd64 10.2.1-6
> 2022-10-18 10:37:01 status unpacked libstdc++6:amd64 12.2.0-5
> ```

`apt-get` is not available anymore, but it leaves `dpkg`, a C application and thus not affected, to fix the problem.

So revert what you tried to installed that isn't intended for Debian 11: most likely `lokinet-bin` (its suffix does suggest it's not for Debian 11 but future Debian 12).

```
dpkg --purge lokinet-bin
```

Download from out-of-band information the correct `libstdc++6` package. On any other *functional* Debian 11 system this would work:

```
apt-get --print-uris download libstdc++6
```

which could for example return (today):

```
'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc%2b%2b6_10.2.1-6_amd64.deb' libstdc++6_10.2.1-6_amd64.deb 492540 SHA256:5c155c58935870bf3b4bfe769116841c0d286a74f59eccfd5645693ac23f06b1
```

which could then be downloaded from any mirror, including the mirror above, either from an other system and then transferred or directly on the damaged system if a download tool is available:

```
curl -JRLO 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc%2b%2b6_10.2.1-6_amd64.deb'
```

and be compared with the checksum from above:

```
$ sha256sum libstdc%2b%2b6_10.2.1-6_amd64.deb
5c155c58935870bf3b4bfe769116841c0d286a74f59eccfd5645693ac23f06b1  libstdc%2b%2b6_10.2.1-6_amd64.deb
```

checksums match.

You can also get it following links at https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libstdc++6 or from https://snapshot.debian.org/

Finally install it over the offending version on the damaged system:

```
dpkg -i libstdc%2b%2b6_10.2.1-6_amd64.deb
```

`apt-get` should now become functional.

Before attempting again what you tried, please have a look at this Debian wiki: [DontBreakDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) and especially [Don't make a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian), because that's exactly what happened in this case.

Comment: Wow! Now it works. Thanks a lot for your amazing help in details.